# Emscripten: null terminate Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

I'm parsing files read in using FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer() as

```js
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function() {
  var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);
  const data_ptr = Module._malloc(data.length);
  if (data_ptr == null) {
     display_error("Could not allocate " + data.length + " bytes for file " + file.name);
  }
  else {
    Module.HEAPU8.set(data, data_ptr);

    var readSample = cwrap("readSample", "number", ["number", "number"]);
    var ret = readSample(data_ptr, data.length);
    Module._free(data_ptr);
  }
}

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

It would be nice if `data_ptr` were null terminated, though checking that the C code doesn't go past data.length works. One thought is to call `Module._malloc(data.length + 1)` and add the null character inside C. Thoughts?

Comment: Null termination is only useful on strings where 0 is not a legal character. Data tends to use 0 a lot as a legal value.

Comment: @stark, this takes in a text file, so there won't be null values inside it.

Comment: In that case why uint8_t and not char?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a CharArray() in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Module._malloc(data.length + 1)` followed by setting the last element to null inside the C code does seem to work. @GirkovArpa's answer is a bit slower (about 10% slower for the first file read and 30% or so slower for the second based on `console.time()`).

Answer (score 0):

You could null-terminate `data` itself so that `data_ptr` points to a null-terminated array of `char`:

```js
var data = new Uint8Array([...new Uint8Array(reader.result), 0]);
```

Comment: This works. Is it efficient? New to JS, but if these new operators just create 'view's of the data, may not be so bad?